# Create ext4 img from diff

Tags: debian, ext4, disk-image, mkfs

I'm trying to create an update image from an ext4 filesystem which should only consists of the changed files. So basically I have a Debian distro with an ext4 root file system. I want to create a base image A from that and install updates afterwards (e.g. apt upgrade). After the update I want to create another image B.
Is there someway to create a "diff image" by comparing what changed between image A and image B so I don't have to copy the full image B all the time?
The reason for this is that the final image should be mounted on another device and all the changes should just be copied over (think of it as updating the second device with the changes from the update of the first device).

Comment: There is incremental mode in `btrfs send` (see `man 8 btrfs-send`). After you send a full snapshot A so it's available on the source and on the destination, you do whatever you need on the source, make a snapshot B and use `btrfs send -p …` to generate a stream describing changes. The stream can be stored in a regular file. Eventually it should be given (via stdin) to `btrfs receive` on the destination. Having access to A the tool will recreate B there. *But* it's for Btrfs, not for ext4. For arbitrary files (which may contain ext4 filesystem): [`rdiff`](https://superuser.com/a/1523459/432690)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the "diff image" will work at the filesystem level like you want it to.  There are too many variables in the placement of files/directories, metadata checksums (on newer systems), journal blocks, etc. that make it impossible to take a block-level diff from one filesystem and apply it to another filesystem *even if the two filesystems were originally identical*.  If there have been *any* modifications to the second filesystem during normal use, then applying a *block level* diff would corrupt the second filesystem.  In some cases the corruption might be minor (e.g. inconsistent free block/inode counts in the superblocks or group descriptors), in other cases there would be significant corruption (e.g. incorrect bitmaps, journal blocks, etc).

What would be more practical is to use a *file level* diff, which is essentially "rsync" (or a parallel version thereof), and would not be ext4 specific.  You may be able to speed up the rsync process by having an fsnotify watcher on the filesystem during the upgrade to generate a list of all modified files so that a full filesystem scan is not needed.

Comment: rsync was the correct trigger, thanks for that. Somehow I was so focused on diffing my ext4 image that I completely forgot about incremental backups with rsync. So my current solution is `rsync -av --delete /home /etc [...] /base`, apt-updating afterwards and then do the incremental diff `rsync -avxHp /home --compare-dest /base /diff`. My /diff is an ext4 file system mounted from an image.